# Pass/bind data from ng-repeat to a child component in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I am learning Angular and I am trying to figure out how to pass/bind data to a child component. I have a main template that has the following:

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="data in treeCtrl.tree" ng-include="'templates/node.html'"></div>
```

Where treeCtrl comes from ui-router state:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('tree', {
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'TreeController as treeCtrl',
    url: '',
    template: '<ui-view/>',
    resolve: {
      treeData: ['TreeData', function(TreeData) {
        return TreeData.data();
      }]
    }
  })
```

And in node.html I am displaying the component:

```
 <action-form data="data.label"></action-form>
```

The action form component is defined in the following manner:

```
  (function () {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('dTreeApp')
    .component('actionForm', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/action.component.html',
      bindings: {
        data: '='
      },
      controller: actionFormController
    });

  function actionFormController() {
  }
})();
```

And in action.component.html I have:

```
<p>data is : {{data}} </p>
<p>data is : {{data.label}} </p>
```

I end up getting the component displayed correctly except the data is not being passed properly. I tried updating the binding in the component definition to use `=`, `<` `@` but none yielded any results.

Comment: try data="data" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix retrieve the desired data using the controller key in the template. I did not have to change anything else. Here is how the template looks like now:

```
<p>data is : {{$ctrl.data |json}} </p>
<p>data is : {{$ctrl.data.label}} </p>
```

The first line will not print the data if I am not passing it in the `form-action` attributes but `data.label` prints fine. once I change

```
<action-form data="data.label"></action-form>
```

to

```
<action-form data="data"></action-form>
```

The lines both print the data in json format and the label property.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok to me

What's wrong is your binding. If you want to bind against data (you expect to use `data` and `data.label` according to your code) then you should bind against it, and not against `data.label`

Do this then.

```
<action-form data="data"></action-form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, yea I tired that, and it did not work. that's why I am trying to print `data` and `data.label` which should be a property. nothing is being printed or logged in the consoled as an error.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle so we can play with it ?

Comment: I updated the question to show where treeCtrl is coming from. I will work on a gett a jsfiddle version. It will take me some time to strip out other non-relevant parts.

Comment: but you didn't add actionFormController definition.. or is it empty ? you are resolving in $state your tree data but never making it part of actionFormController's scope. (or that's what I believe)

Comment: Basically I just want to pass an object to the component from the template. Using a component is probably not the ideal way for this usecase, but  I trying to learn. let me see if I can extract a working plunker/jsfiddle example.

Comment: so in template I used `$ctrl` and now it works `<p>data is : {{$ctrl.data |json}} </p>
<p>data is : {{$ctrl.data.label}} </p>` that's the only thing I changed. Not sure what the significance is.